# How to use the JavaScript Elasticsearch client errors?

Tags: javascript, express, elasticsearch

I'm trying to parse the error from the Elasticsearch client called through a nodeJs express routes. I my case it is the timeout error I would like to identify.

I more or less implement something like that:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client( {
  host: process.env.ELASTICSEARCHLOCATION,
  requestTimeout:500,
  maxRetries:1
});

function returnResponse( response ) {
  return function ( resp ) {
    //stringExtract 
    if ( resp.hits && resp.hits.hits ) {
      response.status( 200 ).send( resp.hits.hits );
    }else{
      response.status( 200 ).send( [] );
    }
  };
}

function handleError( response ) {
  return function( err ){
    if ( err.statusCode == 404 ) {
      response.status( 200 ).send( [] );
    } else {
      console.error( err.message );
      response.status( err.statusCode ).send( err );
    }
  }
}
router.get( "/test", function ( req, res, next ) {
  log.data( "route GET: ", "/wynsureSearch/test" );
  log.request( req.url );

  client .search( {
    index: process.env.ELASTICSEARCHINDEX, //target the wynsure version aka the ES DB index
    type: [], //target the wynsure types
    body: req.body
  }).then( returnResponse( res ), handleError( res ) );
})
```

All works fine when there are no errors. But when a timeout error occurs, the breakpoint in the function returned by `handleError()` shows me this:
[image]

I read from [elastic.co errors documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/errors.html) that there are standars errors. How I have my function match matching the errors from documentation? I would like to be able to match RequestTimeout or InternalServerError for example.

Answer (score 0):

`res` parameter passed in returnResponse and handleError refers to the parameter passed in `router.get( "/test", function ( req, res, next ) {` therefore it is `undefined`.

Quote from [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-conventions.html#api-conventions-cb)

> When a callback is passed to any of the API methods, it will be called with (err, response, status). If you prefer to use promises, don’t pass a callback and a promise will be returned. The promise will either be resolved with the response body, or rejected with the error that occured (including any 300+ response for non "exists" methods).

```
client .search( {
  index: process.env.ELASTICSEARCHINDEX, //target the wynsure version aka the ES DB index
  type: [], //target the wynsure types
  body: req.body }, function callback(err, response, status){
  if (err) {
    if(status == 404) res.status(200).send();
    else console.error(err.message);
  }
  else res.status(200).send(response); // res variable is refering to HTTP response whereas response is the result returned from elasticsearch.
 });
```

Note: status codes in ElasticSearch have their own meaning, don't confuse them with HTTP status codes.

Note: Javascript supports enclosing scopes, not block scopes.

Comment: I can assure you that `res` is not undefined. Otherwise, all seems to work fine with my callbacks (enclosing scopes including) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the undefined status code, there seems to be a [bug with the status code definition in ElasticSearch.JS](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/390#issuecomment-208808546).

[@Spalger](https://github.com/spalger) offers a solution about how using the JavaScript Elasticsearch client errors?:

```
// require the Error class
var EsClientRequestTimeout = require('elasticsearch').errors.RequestTimeout;

// ... somewhere else in your code

client.search(..., function (err) {
  if (err instanceof EsClientRequestTimeout) {
    console.log('timeout')
  } else {
    console.log('not a timeout')
  }
})
```

Thank you a lot [@Spalger](https://github.com/spalger) for helping!